# how to rapidly extract intraframe from a video (in c++ or python)

Tags: c++, python, video, ffmpeg, keyframe

i want to capture some frame from a video so i used command like this:

```
ffmpeg -i MyVideo.mp4 -ss 1:20:12 -vframes 1 test-pic.jpg
```

but ffmpeg proccess frame from begin of video so this command is too slow. i research and i found some article about keyframe so i try to extract keyframe by a command like this

```
ffmpeg -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)" -i MyVideo.mp4 -vsync 2 -s 160x90 -f image2 thumbnails-%02d.jpeg
```

but this command also is to slow and capture too many frame. 
I need a linux command or c++ or python code to capture a frame that dont take long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking%20with%20FFmpeg) states regarding fast seeking:

> **The -ss parameter needs to be specified before -i**:
>
> ffmpeg -ss 00:03:00 -i Underworld.Awakening.avi -frames:v 1 out1.jpg
>
> This example will produce one image frame (out1.jpg) somewhere around
>   the third minute from the beginning of the movie. The input will be
>   parsed using keyframes, which is very fast. The drawback is that it
>   will also finish the seeking at some keyframe, not necessarily located
>   at specified time (00:03:00), so the seeking will not be as accurate
>   as expected.

You could also use hybrid mode, combining fast seeking and slow (decode) seeking, which is kind of the middle ground.

If you want to implement this in C/C++, see the `docs/examples` directory of ffmpeg to get started and `av_seek_frame`.

I recently hacked together [some C code](https://github.com/nmaier/ffthumb/blob/master/thumb.c) to do thumbnails myself, which uses the hybrid mode effectively. May be helpful to you, or not.

Answer (score 0):

[Hello, Mr. Anderson](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-lB3z9d2n9xY/Tocylv5IB8I/AAAAAAAAAz4/sFiR7AE4-UI/s320/Agent-Smith-the-matrix-1954803-1280-1024.jpg).

I'm not familiar with using C++ or Python to do such a thing.  I'm sure it's possible (I could probably get a good idea of how to do this if I researched for an hour), but the time it would take to implement a full solution may outweigh the time cost of finding a better frame capturing program.  After a bit of Googling, I came up with:

1. [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/)
2. [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html)
3. [Frame-shots](http://www.frame-shots.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but I need a solution to use it in my algoritm and my code. I can just use c++ or python code or linux shell command.

Comment: Ok, well like I said, it's do-able.  However, I'm not going to research c++ frame manipulation for you.  [Go get 'em](http://tinyurl.com/nh9vv3z).